# DocuSign TimeZone information in Event notification

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

We are using DocuSign's web-hook event notification to get information about envelopes. In webhook event notification we are getting XML from the webhook request, but all datetime fields like envelope created date, sent date, completed date, declined date or any date's values are always in Pacific Standard Time, even datetime zone information set to IST (India standard time) in DocuSign account. How can we get datetime value as per time zone set in account.

Below is xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>my@email.com</Email><UserName>My Name</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2020-11-19T09:44:07.12</Sent><DeclineReason xsi:nil="true" /><Status>Sent</Status><RecipientIPAddress /><ClientUserId>c2xxxx-xxxxx-47d0-a3a4-xxxxxxxxxx</ClientUserId><CustomFields /><AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus><RecipientId>f759xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx</RecipientId></RecipientStatus></RecipientStatuses><TimeGenerated>2020-11-19T09:44:33.4333381</TimeGenerated><EnvelopeID>67xxxc3-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx</EnvelopeID><Subject>e-Signature - required</Subject><UserName>Acc Name</UserName><Email>my@email.com</Email><Status>Sent</Status><Created>2020-11-19T09:44:06.667</Created><Sent>2020-11-19T09:44:07.277</Sent><ACStatus>Original</ACStatus><ACStatusDate>2020-11-19T09:44:06.667</ACStatusDate><ACHolder>Ac holder</ACHolder><ACHolderEmail>my@email.com</ACHolderEmail><ACHolderLocation>DocuSign</ACHolderLocation><SigningLocation>Online</SigningLocation><SenderIPAddress>100.000.00.000 </SenderIPAddress><EnvelopePDFHash /><CustomFields><CustomField><Name>myid</Name><Show>False</Show><Required>False</Required><Value>000</Value></CustomField><CustomField><Name>sxxxname</Name><Show>False</Show><Required>False</Required><Value>my value</Value></CustomField><CustomField><Name>ename</Name><Show>False</Show><Required>False</Required><Value>test</Value></CustomField></CustomFields><AutoNavigation>true</AutoNavigation><EnvelopeIdStamping>true</EnvelopeIdStamping><AuthoritativeCopy>false</AuthoritativeCopy><DocumentStatuses><DocumentStatus><ID>1</ID><Name>test document.pdf</Name><TemplateName /><Sequence>1</Sequence></DocumentStatus></DocumentStatuses></EnvelopeStatus></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a bug. I am investigating this and will open a bug for the product team if I'm unable to match a different time zone in events. Thank you for reporting this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update: We will be adding an option in the admin page to show the timestamps in the timezone where they occured at some point in the future. For now, you will need to reach out to customer service to enable that enabled. Again, thank you for reporting this issue.

Comment: certificate for envelope always generated as per timezone set in account.. is there any other way or any api available to get account's timezone information?

Comment: As you suggested If we contact customer service and enable that feature then in event notification all timestamp will have timezone information?

Comment: if you set `includeTimeZone` to true, then the timezone will be displayed in the connect event. The events will be in PST for now.